# Open Office - How to change figure numbering?

Tags: openoffice, word-processing, openoffice-writer

In Open Office Writer, I have several figures (Images with captions) on a page, but the figure numbers are ordered incorrectly (e.g. 6, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4).

How can I change their ordering? I can't find where it is possible to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple images with captions all on a single page, my guess is that open office is confused about the 'anchor order' of your images.  Writer auto numbers according to the 'anchor order', and the order being applied is not what it looks like - possibly you moved the pictures around after pasting them into your document? You can anchor things as a paragraph or as a character.  Character gives you more control.  If they all anchor to the same paragraph, then I'm not sure how OO will decide to number them, but it may very well not turn out how you expect.

[image: anchor as character example from openoffice.blogs.com]

An other solution you can use to help ensure the anchor order is exactly what you expect is to paste your images into a table.

### See Also

1. [OpenOffice.org Training Tips](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2009/01/how-to-insert-graphics-in-openoffice-writer-that-are-reasonably-manageable.html) for some advice on your exact problem.